# Gibbs free energy of mixing in a control volume

Tags: acid-base, thermodynamics, computational-chemistry, free-energy, mixtures

I'm trying to model the amount of energy lost due to mixing of a $\mathrm{HCl}$ solution using the Gibbs free energy of mixing. However, I really like a second opinion on the model and the results, because think the energy is high when compared to the theoretical available energy density. The model results in $\sim7\textrm{ kWh/m}^3$ change in Gibbs energy from mixing compared to theoretical available energy of $11.1\textrm{ kWh/m}^3$  for $1\textrm{ M HCl}$ in a acid base flow battery$^1$. Is this change in Gibbs energy then all transformed in heat if we assume no energy is used for work?

#### Model

[image: model schematic]

A concentration $c$ ($\mathrm{M}$) is flowing out of the control volume which models a tank with flow rate $F$ ($\mathrm{L/s}$). A constant amount of moles per seccond is taken out of the outcoming concentration, called the mole rate $J$ ($\textrm{mol/s}$). The returning concentration $c_r$ ($\mathrm{M}$) flows back in the control volume with the same flow rate $F$ ($\mathrm{L/s}$) .

Mass balance for the control volume can be written as
$$
V\frac{dc}{dt} = Fc_r - Fc
$$
With returning concentration $c_r$
$$
c_r = \max\left(\frac{J}{F} + c,\:0\right)
$$
Note that the returning concentration $c_r$ is capped at $0$ to make sure negative concentrations don't occur. Concentration after mixing is written as
$$
c_m= c+\frac{dc}{dt}\Delta t
$$
Homogenous mixing of the concentration in the control volume is assumed after time 2. Therefore we can say that
$$
\Delta G_{mix} = G_2 - G_1 = G_{m} - (G_{c}+G_{d})
$$
Where $G_m$, $G_c$, and $G_d$ are the Gibbs energy after mix, of the concentrated part, and the diluted part respectively ($\textrm{J}$). Here Gibbs energy is:
$$
G = \sum_i \mu_in_i
$$
Where $\mu_i$ is the chemical potential of component $i$ in the solution ($\textrm{J/mol}$), and $n_i$ is the number of moles of component $i$ in the solution. The chemical potential for ideal solutions without pressure change and charge transport can be written as
$$
\mu_i = \mu_i^0 + RT\ln x_i
$$
Where $\mu_i^0$ is the standard chemical potential ($\textrm{J/mol}$), $R$ the universal gas constant $[8.314\textrm{ J/mol.K}],$ $T$ temperature ($\textrm{R}$), $x_i$ the mole fraction$^2$.

Replacing $n$ by $cV$, and substituting $\mu_i$ in the $\Delta G_{mix}$ results in
$$
\Delta G_{mix} = \sum_{i}\left( \left[ c_mVRT\ln x_{m} \right]_{mix} - \left[ c(V-F\Delta t)RT\ln{x_c}  \right]_{con} - \left[ c_r(F\Delta t)RT\ln{x_r} \right]_{dil} \right)
$$
Note that the standard chemical potential $\mu_i^0$ is elliminated.

Replacing the summation for $2$, because we have two ions with the same concentration in the system, and writing $\Delta G_{mix}$ in differential form leads to the final equation of
$$
\frac{dG_{mix}}{dt} = 2FRT(c\ln{x_c} - c_r \ln{x_r})
$$

To calculate the mole fractions for $HCl$ a linear interpolation is used
$$
x_{HCl}(c) = 0.0169 c + 0.0004
$$
Thus, making the mole fraction per ion
$$
x_{i}(c) = \frac{0.0169 c + 0.0004}{2}
$$

#### Parameters

- $t_{f}=20\cdot(3600\textrm{ s})$, final time (run time of $20\textrm{ h}$)
- $V = 1000\textrm{ L}$
- $T = 293 \textrm{ K}$, room temperature.
- $F=5V / t_{f} \approx 0.14\textrm{ L/s}$, flushing the entire volume every 2 hours.
- $J = -2c_0V/t_f\approx0.028\textrm{ mol/s}$, if all the way linear then from $1\textrm{ M}$ to $0\textrm{ M}$ in $10\textrm{ h}$.

Inital conditions

- $c_0 = 1\textrm{ M}$

#### Results

Concentration over time:

[image]

Energy change over time:

[image]

#### References

1. W.J. van Egmond, et al. Performance of an environmentally benign acid base flow
   battery at high energy density; *International Journal of Energy Research Volume 42, Issue 4*, **2018** ([PDF](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdfdirect/10.1002/er.3941))
2. Kitty Nijmeijer, Sybrand Metz. Chapter 5 Salinity Gradient Energy; *Sustainability Science and Engineering Volume 2*, **2010** ([link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1871271109002050))

Comment: the equation you used for chemical potential is for an ideal gas, not an aqueous solution.  In addition, this system is really, in essence a closed system.